# Fixing the width of the elements inside a div display as table

Tags: css, row, css-tables

I have problem fixing the width of the elements inside a div display as table, I realized that the caption causing this problem, I tried to fix it with no success, here is the example :

Here is the code:

```css
.row {
  display:table;
  border-spacing:10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row-element {
  display: table-cell;
}
.row-element input{
  width:100%;
  line-height:20px;
}
.row-element label{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #2E2F3F;
display: table-caption;
white-space: nowrap;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row-element">
    <label>Name#<span class="mandatory"> *</span></label>
 <input data="true" type="text" class="textfield error" title="Name" minlength="5" maxlength="15" message="Insert Your Name !" name="NAME_FIELD" mandatory="">
     </div>
     <div class="row-element"><label>Outside Label &gt; <span class="mandatory"> *</span></label>
     
       <input data="true" type="text" class="textfield error" minlength="5" maxlength="15" message="Insert Your Name !" name="NAME_FIELD" mandatory="">
     </div> 
<div class="row-element">
  <label>custom_mandatory text#<span class="mandatory"> (Please Specify)</span></label>
  <input data="true" type="text" class="textfield error" mandatory-text="(Please Specify)" title="custom mandatory text" message="Insert Your Name !" name="NAME_FIELD" mandatory="">
 </div>      
 </div>
```

Comment: here is my example : http://codepen.io/pen/vGeBKN

Comment: It's not clear what is the desired result

Comment: if you open the link mentioned in my first comment, you will see that inputs are not same, every element mus have the same width, this is the problem bumpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after? I added `table-layout: fixed;` to `row` and some arbitrary width to `row-element`.

```css
.row {
  display:table;
  border-spacing:10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.row-element {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}
.row-element input{
  width:100%;
  line-height:20px;
}
.row-element label{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #2E2F3F;
display: table-caption;
white-space: nowrap;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row-element">
    <label>Name#<span class="mandatory"> *</span></label>
 <input data="true" type="text" class="textfield error" title="Name" minlength="5" maxlength="15" message="Insert Your Name !" name="NAME_FIELD" mandatory="">
     </div>
     <div class="row-element"><label>Outside Label &gt; <span class="mandatory"> *</span></label>
     
       <input data="true" type="text" class="textfield error" minlength="5" maxlength="15" message="Insert Your Name !" name="NAME_FIELD" mandatory="">
     </div> 
<div class="row-element">
  <label>custom_mandatory text#<span class="mandatory"> (Please Specify)</span></label>
  <input data="true" type="text" class="textfield error" mandatory-text="(Please Specify)" title="custom mandatory text" message="Insert Your Name !" name="NAME_FIELD" mandatory="">
 </div>      
 </div>
```

Comment: Wow, its working perfectly :D , Thank you so much bumby, Appreciated